# iOS XHTwitterPaggingViewer : Difference between two reference of storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

Can someone tell me what is the difference between two line, both are reference the View controller.

1.

> ```
> UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
> XHTwitterPaggingViewer *twitterPaggingViewer = (XHTwitterPaggingViewer *)navigationController.topViewController;
> ```

2.

> ```
> XHTwitterPaggingViewer *twitterPaggingViewer = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"XHTwitterPaggingViewer"];
> ```

If I am go with first then my app work perfect, other on second it will crash.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you use the twitterPaggingViewController instance which was instantiated from the application start. (I assume you implemented this correct as you did not gave us more source code)

The second example creates a new instance from a storyboard.

Comment: Hello Oliver, here is the exact issue which i am facing. https://github.com/xhzengAIB/TwitterPaggingViewer/issues/13